# Superfish menu Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla2.5

I'm using superfish menu for a Joomla website. The problem I have has to do with the menu time delay. here is the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/tBZPe/6/ 
 it is working fine here. But when I do the same styling on my website it looses all the jQuery functionality.

This is the jQuery I have used:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("#menu").superfish({
      delay: 5000,
      onHide: function () { jQuery("#HideThis").hide(); }
 });
jQuery("#Stuff").click(function () { jQuery("#HideThis").show() });
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the version of joomla was not compatible with the version of superfish menu I was using. so I upgraded my joomla from 1.7.1 to joomla 2.5.11
then I have installed superfish version 2 then problem solved